# How do you attach to events on a ScriptObject in Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, xaml, scripting

The HtmlObject provides all the necessary functionality to register managed event handlers for script and DOM events, but what if the class you need to listen to doesn't exist as a DOM element, but a scripting variable (referenced via ScriptObject) instead?

Comment: Can you please explain what the script object and JavaScript syntax are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by AnthonyWJones, Silverlight can't attached to JavaScript events.  The right thing to do in this situation is to do the following:

Enable scripting access in Silverlight:

1. Mark the class with the
   ScriptableType attribute, or mark
   the specific methods with
   ScriptableMember
2. Call
   HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject in
   the constructor.

Once everything is set up in the Silverlight code, here's what you do in JavaScript:

1. Obtain a reference to the JavaScript
   object and register an event handler
2. Use document.getElementById to get
   the Silverlight control
3. Call .Content.. in the
   JavaScript event handler. For
   example,
   silverlight.Content.Page.UpdateText(text).

So basically, all event handling is performed in JavaScript, but the JavaScript event handlers can be used to call functions in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

A javascript object doesn't support the concept of attached events.  However it may support the concept of a property holding a reference to function that if assigned will be called at a certain point.

I take you have such an object?

If so you use the ScriptObject SetProperty method using the name of the property that should hold a reference to a function and a delegate to Managed method matches the signature that the Javascript object will call.

*Caveat* the following is untested at this point but should put you on the right path.

```
//Javascript in web page.
var myObj = new Thing();

function Thing()
{
     this.doStuff = function()
     {
         if (this.onstuff) this.onstuff("Hello World");
     }
}

// C# code in a Silverlight app.

class SomeClass
{
    private ScriptObject myObject;
    public SomeClass(ScriptObject theObject)
    {
         myObject = theObject;
         myObject.SetProperty("onstuff", (Action<string>)onstuff);
    } 

    function void onstuff(string message)
    {
         //Do something with message
    }

}
```